# TF-IDF Vectorizer Search Query Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sparse-matrix, tf-idf

I have converted some documents to create a TF-IDF Vectorizer. Now I want to handle search queries and return list of pages in decreasing order of TF-IDF value. I am able to get the position of the query term in the 'vocabulary_'. However as it is a sparse matrix, I am not able to read the tf-idf value at that index. Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `todense()` on the element before you read it.

Reference: [scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.todense](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.todense.html)